# SSIS 2005 Transformations Used for Auditing?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two tables in our data warehouse which need to be audited on several levels. The structure of the first table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EnctrAPR](
[EncounterNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[MedRec] [varchar](50) NULL,
[AdmitDate ] [datetime] NULL,
[DischargeDate ] [datetime] NULL,
[Age ] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Disposition ] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DRG ] [varchar](50) NULL,
[APRDRG ] [varchar](50) NULL,
[APRDRGWeight] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SOI] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ROM] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Age18] [bit] NULL,
[Age18To64] [bit] NULL,
[Age65] [bit] NULL,
[BowelObstruction] [bit] NULL,
[AMI] [bit] NULL,
[CABG] [bit] NULL,
[Valve] [bit] NULL,
[PCI] [bit] NULL,
[Sepsis] [bit] NULL,
[GSP] [bit] NULL,
[HF] [bit] NULL,
[Stroke] [bit] NULL,
[Pneumonia] [bit] NULL,
[DKA] [bit] NULL,
[GIBleed] [bit] NULL,
[Pancreatitis] [bit] NULL,
[RF] [bit] NULL,
[PE] [bit] NULL,
[COPD] [bit] NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_EnctrAPR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EncounterNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to do several audits against another table in the data warehouse.  They are:
Identify records in above table that aren't in the DWH table.
Identify records in the DWH table that aren't in the above table.
Document records where each of the bit fields above is TRUE but are FALSE in the DWH.
Confirm overall record count for a given date range.

Can I use SSIS to accomplish these audits?  Or, would a combinaion of stored procedures and SSIS be the best bet?  Please provide me with some suggestions on ow to best automate such auditing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Lookup Transformation in SSIS to accomplish this, but this component is a little slow. If the databases are on different servers I would be inclined to use SSIS. If they are in the same instance, I would probably use a Stored Procedure without SSIS.

If you do use the SSIS approach, you would have a OLEDB source to read the rows from ODH, a lookup transformation against the table above and then write the results out to a destination.

I see no benefit on combining SSIS and an SP for this specific task.

Comment: The tables are on the same instance.  So, it sounds like a SP would be my best bet?  If so, are there any particular ways you'd suggest comparing the data in the two tables?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. You could use EXISTS/NOT EXISTS or EXCEPT/INTERSECT. Personally I prefer EXCEPT for readability, but may not perform quite as well. For the BIT columns, you could use a join, joining on key = key and bitcol <> bitcol

Comment: One more question on EXCEPT:  My primary key field in Table A is longer than that in Table B.  I need to substring the field in table A to get it to match that in table B.  Can I still use EXCEPT?

Comment: Yes, the result of the substring just needs to be implicitly castable to the data type of the other table